# Any way to undo using an alchemical tome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-equivalent-exchange

So, as the title says: I made the foolish mistake of 'using' an alchemical tome, which means I now find it basically impossible to find ANYTHING on my transmutation slab.

Is there a data file somewhere I can remove to wipe the settings for the transmutation tablet? Somewhere in a config folder?

My plan would be to make the few useful items I can actually find, then wipe the settings and learn those items again...

I'm playing SMP, but it's a friend's server so I can get him to remove files if needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the Data subfolder in the save folder of the world there will be a file detailing the items unlocked by the tablet called `tablet_<yourname>.dat`

this is what you need to delete

you could also copy someone else's dat so you don't have to redo all that work

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to find enough useful items to be able to reset and not worry too much, I'll just add them back in afterwards. Cheers for the help!